# Would it be a bad idea to make a joke campaign?

Tags: new-players, campaign-development, new-gm

I want to DM for a group of friends that have had minimal amount of tabletop role-playing experience (two sessions of a D&D campaign and three sessions of a Dungeon World campaign, both DM'ed by one of the friends). It would be my first time DM'ing, and I don't want to be too railroading or player-punishing, as the friend who DM'ed last might have been too restrictive for us (in fairness to him it was all our first times and we suffered from "My Guy" syndrome), and this led to the campaigns being cut short due to lack of interest/fun.

In wanting to make one myself that lasted to completion and everyone enjoyed, I ended up getting a little ambitious and designed an entire class/race/move/etc system, as well as a world to fit in with it specifically for this campaign (I should also note that I have zero experience building this kind of system, and it is probably somewhat unbalanced). For the most part, the world and systems it employs are jokey--not at all to be taken seriously--and being a bare bones structure, for the express purpose of letting my PC's flesh out how the world works based on how they interact with it, so nobody gets too bored (knowing my player-base, anything too heavy handed would result in disinterest).

My question is, as a first time DM for players who are also generally new, would it be a bad idea to run a jokey, fun-based campaign? I understand that it's just a game and games should be fun, but I fear giving my players expectations and setting precedents for future campaigns DM'd by myself that I would like to take more seriously, campaigns by other DM's they might play, or even worse, campaigns they might make down the road.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. This is an interesting question that, in my opinion, is going to be hard to craft a definitive answer for, in that there'd be so much opinion revolving about what's fun, what's boring, what your players' futures may hold.... I've voted to hold this question so that we can see about finding an answerable core-problem in your question. On the other hand, you may simply be better off *discussing* this than looking for Q&A: we have a [list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23970) we recommend for that purpose, including our very own [chat].

Comment: General challenges of purposefully humorous campaigns or settings and problems with homebrewing both content and mechanics as a newcomer aside (both could likely be answered), answers for this depend entirely on your players, how your campaign goes and probably a plethora of other factors. Who knows how much lasting impact it will have on each individual? One might see it as unsuccessful individual attempt and hope for better, another might perceive it as the third unpleasant RPG experience in a row and drop the hobby, a third might like it and be disappointed by other campaigns. Unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I made the experience that a campaigns "joke-ness" depends more on the players than the DM or the used system. On the other hand, if the players don't tend to enjoy a certain silliness, or tend to occasionally be silly themselves, doing a "silly" campaign will feel forced and generally fall flat. Do you have non-RPG gaming experiences with the players? You can probably infer a lot by looking at the kind of games they enjoy.

So, without some knowledge of the players, I would not try to do a joke-filled, kind of silly campaign.